# Retrieve JPEG image from a redirected URL and display it on a GUI window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to download a JPEG file from a URL and display it on a tkinter GUI window

This is the code I am trying to use to download and display the JPEG:

```
picURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + ID + "/picture"
picBytes= urlopen(picURL).read()
picData = io.BytesIO(picBytes)
picPil = Image.open(picData)
picTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(picPil)
label_9 = Label(image = picTK, bg = "blue").pack()
```

The problem is that the image isn't showing up. All I get is a blue box. How can i make it so the picture is shown?

Thanks

Im using python 3.3 on windows

Answer (score 2):

What library are you using to access the image? I would recommend [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It automatically handles redirects for you:

```
import requests
import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

r = requests.get(https://graph.facebook.com/userID/picture)
im = Image.open(StringIO(r.content))
```

Comment: can I use that library on windows?

Comment: I would imagine you could.

Comment: Install pip:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Then `pip install requests`

Comment: it turns out "urlopen" was getting the redirected url so I dont need to use requests. the problem is now that the image just isn't showing up

Answer (score 0):

Try with Tkinter

```
import Tkinter 
import Image, ImageTk
#open image and convert to byte format
im = Image.open('photo.jpg').convert2byte()
root = Tkinter.Tk()
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
Tkinter.Label(root, image=tkimage).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also, see a related question [Showing image in Gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213662/showing-image-in-gui)

Comment: that wont work, because i dont have the image stored, i need to get it from the redirected link but by only knowing the first one