# Image in Tkinter Label?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am new to python GUI programming, I want to add a image in my tkinter label, I have created the following code but the window is not showing my image. Path of image is the same folder as this code.

```
import ImageTk
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image


def make_label(master, x, y, w, h, img, *args, **kwargs):
    f = Frame(master, height = h, width = w)
    f.pack_propagate(0) 
    f.place(x = x, y = y)
    label = Label(f, image = img, *args, **kwargs)
    label.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
    return label


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    frame = tk.Frame(root, width=400, height=600, background='white')
    frame.pack_propagate(0)
    frame.pack()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('logo.png'))
    make_label(root, 0, 0, 400, 100, img)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Is this your actual code? If not, my guess would be that the [image is garbage collected](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15435134/1639625). Do you get any error?

Comment: No there is no error, just an empty window.

Comment: As I said, works fine for me... so if this is your original code, could it be that your 'logo.png' in in fact much bigger and you are seeing just the top-left (white) corner of it? Also, what exact python version are you using?

Comment: Got it, logo.png was too large to be displayed. Thanks !!

Comment: You can use `Image.open('logo.png').resize((400,100))` to resize it.

Answer (score 9):

For debugging purpose try to avoid the use of PIL and load some *.gif (or another acceptable) file directly in PhotoImage, like shown below, if it'll work for you then just convert your image in *.gif or try to deal with PIL.

```
from tkinter import *

def make_label(parent, img):
    label = Label(parent, image=img)
    label.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root, width=400, height=600, background='white')
    frame.pack_propagate(0)    
    frame.pack()
    img = PhotoImage(file='logo.gif')
    make_label(frame, img)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
       img = Image.open('image_name')
       self.tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
       Label(self,image = self.tkimage).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does, and how it fixes the OP's problem. Code-only answers without explanation are not useful to other readers, and therefore will likely attract downvotes.